# Не работает тег с ссылкой

Tags: html, ссылка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    <head>




    <body>
        <a>https://www.youtube.com/</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в теге ссылки укажите атрибут href

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/">название ссылки</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="ссылка">текст</a>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]